# ValidateAntiForgeryToken + Botão voltar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Bom dia.

Tenho um formulário de login em uma página web usando MVC 5, estou usando a função [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] para fazer a validação do formulários por questões de segurança.

A página faz login corretamente, porém ao clicar no botão Voltar do navegador e inserir novamente os dados de login aparece a mensagem

O token antifalsificação fornecido destinava-se ao usuário "", mas o usuário atual é "1747".

Como faço para arrumar isso?

Obrigado

`

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(usuarioModel user)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentativa de login inválida.");
            return View();
        }

        if (usuarioAplicacao.AutenticarUsuario(user.Cnpj, user.Usuario, user.Senha2))
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Grid", "Atendimento");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentativa de login inválida.");
            return View();
        }
    }`
```

```
@model usuarioModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Efetuar login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml";
}
Login
 Faça o login para acessar a sua área. 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "home", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    
        
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cnpj, new { @class = "form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix form-group", autocomplete = "on", placeholder = "CNPJ" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Cnpj, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        
        
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Usuario, new { @class = "form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix form-group", autocomplete = "on", placeholder = "Usuário" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Usuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        
    
    
        
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Senha2, new { @class = "form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix form-group", autocomplete = "on", placeholder = "Senha" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Senha2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        
        
            
        
    
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

`
```

Comment: E quanto a seu formulário? Pode adicionar o HTML?

Comment: @Aline Adicionei

Comment: Que estranho, simulei aqui e não ocorre esse problema comigo. Imagino que você tenha outra action `Index()` (**GET**) usada para renderizar a página (pois esse teu é o POST). Coloca um breakpoint na action **GET**, e quando você clicar no botão "voltar" do browser, verifique se está caindo nesse método. Além disso, se puder, compartilhe também o que esse método `AutenticarUsuario` faz.